# Как сделать так, чтобы массива начинался не с 0, а 1 индекса ?

Tags: python

```
l = list(range(1, 4)) #### 0:{1}, 1:{2}, 2:{3}   
random.shuffle(l)
print(l[1])
```

Comment: Зачем это вам понадобилось?

Comment: Можно написать функцию, которая будет обращаться к листу с вычитанием из индекса единицы. _Но зачем??_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы гарантированно собираетесь сделать что-то плохое, тем не менее сугубо с академической точки зрения: можно создать отдельный класс, наследуемый от `list` и переопределить поведение нужных методов, например `__getitem__`, как то так:

```
class MyList(list):

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return super(MyList, self).__getitem__(index - 1)

>>> my_list = MyList(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> mylist[1]
'a'
```

Только надо решить что конкретно делать при 0 и отрицательных индексах.